# You have to wait x seconds to continue timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I need a php & MySQL script which will do the following:

User presses a button, insert into MySQL table a timestamp, if 60 minutes passed echo a text, if 60 minutes didn't pass echo another text.

Can any one please help me?

Comment: Im pretty sure if you check Google you could find a simple script. Anyhow I have added my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even though we shouldn't do it for you, I will.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $timer = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT timer FROM table WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."');
  if((time() <= $timer['timer']) ) {
  echo "60mins has not passed";
  }else{
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET timer='".strtotime ("+60 seconds")."' WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."'");
    echo "60mins has passed";
  }
}//button pressed
```

Comment: Is this what you were after?

Comment: Ah sorry i tested it , it dosent work and is not really what i need

Comment: Don't forget you must change your variables, rows and tables for it to work. You must adapt it to your website for it to work. I have put the "formula" here for you.

Comment: I created out another method
$user = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from accounts where id = ".$_SESSION['user']));
$lastsent = $user[timer];
$wait = $lastsent + 1800 - time();
echo $wait;

Comment: [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) is deprecated and should not be used. It creates an opportunity for SQL injection. Something like [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) supports prepared statements and will safely handle parameters like this.